# Google fonts issue as per new URL format

Tags: magento2, google, fonts

I have added google font in `default_head_blocks.xml` file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" src_type="url" />
```

And I am facing an error as per below screenshot:
[image]

Kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: I have facing same error, regarding syntax

Comment: check this link --- https://nwdthemes.com/2016/06/16/magento-2-add-google-font/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use below line in your `default_head_blocks.xml` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&amp;display=swap" src_type="url" />
```

There's one **&** symbol, you can use `&amp;` instead of `&` sign in URL, whenever you're trying to insert URLs in XML file.

After changing above line, please try to clear Magento cache using below commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: it's not working dear, I have already try this

Comment: @SatishRana, I have tested and it's working for me. Just add link URL inside <head> tag in your default_head_blocks.xml and flush and clear Magento cache. It'll work.

Comment: @DipeshRangani, Let me know if it works for you then. Thanks.

Comment: it's working, I have tested again may be it's because of browse cache or deployment issue.

Comment: Great, thanks. :-) @SatishRana

Comment: It's working for me as well Thanks @KishanSavaliya..!

Comment: Great, Thanks @DipeshRangani.! :-)